# Finding businesses within an 'n' mile radius of a point with Google Maps or Earth

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, google-earth, openstreetmap

I'm working on an article that seeks to find a certain type of business within my borough. Ideally I'd be able to supply a KML file and have it return only businesses within those bounds, but I'm not super optimistic that's possible and thus am settling for another approach:

given a latitude/longitude set located in the centre of my borough, is there any way for either Google Maps or Earth (or even Bing or OpenStreetMaps or whatever at this point - I'm not picky) to return all businesses within a, say, 2.5 mile radius?

It seems like this is something Google Maps should be able to do; a query like "businesses Z near X,Y" does this somewhat (though it seems there's no way of defining what exactly "near" means).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) to get at this data. It will allow you to specify a Lat/Long coordination and return places based on a radius distance. There is also documentation for [Javascript based application](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Here's some info from the first article on using Place Search:

> The Google Places API allows you to query for place information on a
>   variety of categories, such as: establishments, prominent points of
>   interest, geographic locations, and more. You can search for places
>   either by proximity or a text string. A Place Search returns a list of
>   Places along with summary information about each Place; additional
>   information is available via a Place Details query.

You will need to set up the API project in https://code.google.com/apis/console/ to get the required project `key` parameter.

Example request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=<PROJECT KEY GOES HERE>
```

Comment: Not half bad. That said, specifying a location/radius only *preferences* results -- it doesn't eliminate results outside of that radius.

Comment: Really? According to the documentation the `radius=xxx` parameter should only return results within that distance. The list of business *within* that radius is then ranked by preference by default. Have you tried creating the request? Can you share it here to see what's going?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=strip+clubs&sensor=false&radius=4000&location=51.551715,-0.062069&key=<REMOVED> and https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?keyword=strip+clubs&sensor=false&radius=4000&location=51.551715,-0.062069&key=<REMOVED> both yield similar results. Apologies in advance for the content; the hypothesis of the writer I'm working with is that there's a correlation between strip clubs and higher levels of crime (For the record, not sure I really agree with that).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but `/api/place/textsearch` seems to return results independent of radius, you're right. However, `/api/place/search/` does work. At least when I try to change the radius to `1000` it returns no results. Only when you expand to `4000` do you get anything. Even if it does limit results, are you saying the radial calculation is wrong?

Comment: Good to know re: search vs. textsearch. Doing a bit more fiddling, it seems regular search is working fine -- using Google Maps (as opposed to Google Earth's) measuring tool, all results are within 4000m.

Comment: I'll leave open for a couple days in case somebody has a more robust or user-friendly solution (Find Type X Location within Y distance of Place Z is something I do with a fair degree of regularity); failing that, I'll accept this answer. Thanks!